# A variant of the Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858803/limit-of-a-sum-over-an-increasing-finite-set-dominated-convergence-riemann-in).

Let $S_k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of finite sets where $S_k\subset  S_{k+1}\subset[0,1]$. 
Fixed $s$ in $S_k$, let $s'$ denote the predecessor of $s$ in $S_k$.

Let $f_k:[0,1]\to A$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of functions that converge to $f:[0,1]\to A$ in a pointwise manner.

Now the question is under which conditions it's possible to prove that

$$
\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{s\in S_k} (s-s') f_k(s) = \int_0^1 f(x) \,\mbox{d}x
$$

Comment: I misunderstand: Do you mean each $S_k$ finite set or the number of $S_k$'s finite?

Comment: I mean: $S_k$ has a finite number of elements. And $k$ goes from 1 to $\infty$